# SQL Selecting results with current date in datetime datatype field

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to select the results extracted today where the results contains data with this extracted datetime.2016-09-19 11:01:36.753

i want to extract the results which are having extracted_date as today without considering datatime part.My query is like below

```
select * from tblOrders where extracted_date=DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

or

```
select * from LocalACB.tblEBPInvoice nolock where Extracted_Date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

But the records are not returned. How to achieve this?

Comment: Cast your column to date too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are on the right track there. Just change to checks for `>= today` and `< tomorrow`

```
select * 
from   tblOrders 
where  extracted_date >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
and    extracted_date <  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 1)
```